# Maven and FEST-Swing Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, xvfb, fest

I have some FEST-Swing test and I would like to run it with Maven under linux.
I tried using xvfb like this:

```
xvfb-run mvn -Dtest=e2e.MateriePrimeE2eTest test
```

But I have this error:

```
Running e2e.MateriePrimeE2eTest
Jan 18, 2013 10:26:58 AM org.fest.swing.monitor.WindowStatus <init>
WARNING: Error ocurred when creating a new Robot
java.awt.AWTException: headless environment
at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:75)
at org.fest.swing.util.RobotFactory.newRobotInPrimaryScreen(RobotFactory.java:35)
[...]
```

it's the same without xvfb.

Answer (score 0):

"Headless" means that this code needs access to a graphics environment, and it hasn't.
Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086754/can-i-use-java-awt-robot-from-within-a-daemon) it may help you.